# write jquery array elements

Tags: jquery, arrays

Firstly I add a value to array from input. Later I want to write all array elements. İt stores all array elements. But it just writes last element. How can I do?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter Number:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="data" name="data"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="result"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div id="result2"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>   
            <td><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="adddata();"></td>
            <td><input type="button" value="Write" onclick="myFunction();">    </td>
        </tr>         
    </table>
<script>
    var arr=[];
    function adddata(){
        var data=$("#data").val().split(' ');
            $("#data").val("");
            arr.push(data);                 
    }
        function myFunction() {
            for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
            {
              $("#result2").html("Indeks no: " + i + " = " + arr[i]);
            }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `.html()` to `.append()`, as `.html()` will replaced previous text inside it over and over till the end of the loop and as a result, you will end up with the last element of array written on it.

```
$("#result2").append("Indeks no: " + i + " = " + arr[i]);
```

Comment: I know but I have to wait a while for click. :)